# Pagination Options in KDB

Tags: kdb

I am looking to support a use case that returns kdb datasets back to users. The users connects to kdb using the Java API, runs the query synchronously and retrieves results.

However, issues are coming up when returning larger datasets and therefore I would like to return the data from kdb to the java process in pages/slices. Unfortunately users need to be able to run queries that return millions of rows and it would be easier to handle if they were passed back in slices of say 100,000 rows (Cassandra and other DBs do this sort of thing).

The potential approaches I have come up with are as follows:

1. Run the "where" part of the query on the database and return only the indices/date partitions (if applicable) of the data required. The java process would then use these indices to select the data required slice by slice . This approach would control memory usage on the kdb side as it would not have to load all HDB data required at once. However, overall this would increase the run time of the query as data would have to be searched/queried multiple times. This could work well for simple selects but complicated queries may need to go through an "onboarding" process which I want to avoid.
2. Store results of the query in a global variable in kdb which the java process can then query slice by slice. This simpler method could support any query but could potentially hit limits on the kdb side (memory/timeout) if too large a dataset is queried.

Other points to consider:

- It should support users running queries on any type of process - gateway, hdb, rdb etc
- It should support more than just simple selects e.g.

```
((1!select sym, price from trade where sym=`AAA) uj  
 1!select sym,price from order where sym=`AAA) 
  lj select avgBid:avg bid by sym from quote where sym=`AAA
```

- The paging functionality should be removed from the end user

Does anyone have any views on if there are there any options available other than the ones listed above? Essentially I am looking for a select[m n] type approach that supports any query.

Comment: Why do they need to query soo much data through the API? if it's for a UI i don't see how viewing 1 million records by eye is anyway useful. I don't think either option is great and users should be writing smarter queries which aggregate / cut down the data sufficiently

Comment: It may not add as much overhead as you think. Running the where clause would pull those columns into memory, and you don't need to perform any aggregations on the data until you deliver each page of data. It may only add 10-20% in the end. You might need to handle the case where a by clause reduces the amount of data returned, and then pull more data for that iteration.